# How to deserialize XML Choice to the right Complex Type

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, wsdl, webservice-client

How do I deserialize the return object into the right class type?

Here's the XML markup with three choices (SuccessType, WarningsType and ErrorsType) defined:

```
<xs:element name="TopNode">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Success" type="SuccessType">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Success element.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Warnings" type="WarningsType" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Warning element.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Errors" type="ErrorsType">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Error types element.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here's the generated class in c#

```
public partial class TopNode 
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Errors", typeof(ErrorsType), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Success", typeof(SuccessType), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Warnings", typeof(WarningsType), Order=0)]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }   
}
```

The occurrence of WarningsType can be zero. Here's how I cast and find if WarningsType exists in the returned result from web service.

```
var warningTypes = readResponse.TopNode.Items.FirstOrDefault(r => r.GetType() == typeof(NamespaceA.WarningsType)) as NamespaceA.WarningsType;
if (warningTypes != null) { // my code... }
```

**How to remove the need to search and cast the to the right class type and make the below possible?**

```
var warningTypes = readResponse.TopNode.WarningsType;
```

Comment: Create some test data and then serialize to see what you get.  The schema is showing three different Elements and you are creating an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current solution - Create a generic method that returns the requested type.

```
public partial class TopNode
{
    public T GetItem<T>()
    {
        var result = Items.FirstOrDefault(r => r.GetType() == typeof(T));
        return (T)result;
    }

    public List<T> GetItems<T>()
    {
        var results = Items.Where(r => r.GetType() == typeof(T)).Select(r => (T)r).ToList();
        return (List<T>)results;
    }
}
```

To get the WarningType

```
var warningsType = readResponse.TopNode.GetItems<WarningsType>();
```

But I will have to perform the null test before using it

```
if (warningsType != null)
{
    // code here
}
```